# Convert comma delimited to array for setValues

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to convert this comma delimited string:

```
test1,test2,test3\ntest11,test22,test33
```

to this so i can use it to setValues() on appscript

```
[["test1","test2","test3"],["test11","test22","test33"]]
```

I have this code below which works but it's putting quotes on the sheet. Im sure there's an easier way to do this.

```
function test() {
  var urls = 'test1,test2,test3\ntest11,test22,test33'
  var urlsArr = urls.split(/\n/g)
  var ssResultTotal = ssResult.getLastRow()
  var urlsArrFinal = []
  urlsArr.forEach(function (d, i) {
    var urlsArrSplit = d.split(',')
    var urlsArr2 = []
    urlsArrSplit.forEach(function (dd, ii) {
      urlsArr2.push('"'+dd+'"')
    })
    
    urlsArrFinal.push(urlsArr2)
    // urlsArrFinal.push(d)
    // Logger.log(urlsArr2)
  })
   ssResult.getRange(2,1,urlsArr.length,3).setValues(urlsArrFinal)
  

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(urlsArrFinal))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After you split the newline delimited string, split the comma delimited strings again with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var urls    = 'test1,test2,test3\ntest11,test22,test33';
var urlsArr = urls.split( /\n/g ).map( url => url.split( ',' ) );

console.log( urlsArr );
```

Answer (score 2):

The Thum Choon Tat's answer is perfectly fine and usable as a universal solution.

Here is just an additional variant how it can be done with the native CSV parser in this particular case (since the string `urls` looks like a CSV):

```
function myFunction() {
  var urls = 'test1,test2,test3\ntest11,test22,test33';

  var urlsArray = Utilities.parseCsv(urls);

  console.log(urlsArray);
}
```

[image]